# How to execute code on program exit in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a very simple discord.js bot code. I want to execute some code(set the bot's status to offline) when my program exits. How do i do this? I searched for `onDestroy`(I think it's related to what i want) in the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs), but i only found `Client.destroy()`, which is a method to destroy the client object. Here's some of my code:

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');

require('dotenv').config()
const token = process.env.TOKEN;

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// #region Import commands from other files
// not needed for my question
// #endregion

// #region Import events from other files
// not needed for my question
// #endregion

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution myself. This worked for me:

```
function stopEvent(code) {
    console.log("Stopping. Code "+code+".");
    client.user.setStatus("invisible");
    client.destroy();
}
process.addListener("SIGINT", stopEvent);
process.addListener("SIGTERM", stopEvent);
```

Comment: Worked for me too. :)